# How do I do this in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to know year having temperature greater than prev year.

`Temperature` table:

```
Temperature   YEAR   
------------------
21            2002
75            2005
10            2003
89            2004
100           2001
52            2000
```

I tried this SQL:

```
SELECT X.Year 
FROM TemperatureTable AS X, TemperatureTable AS Y 
WHERE X.Year > Y.Year 
  AND X.Temperature > Y.Temperature;
```

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to and show what you have tried so far

Comment: SELECT X.Year FROM TemperatureTable as X, TemperatureTable as Y WHERE X.Year > Y.Year AND X.Temperature > Y.Temperature;

Comment: This is what I have tried so far

Comment: you don't want X.YEAR > Y.YEAR.  You want X.YEAR = Y.YEAR-1

Comment: @SeanGarrett: I did put your SQL in the query, because it belongs there...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function `lag() over()` as below:

```
select *
    , (case when Temperature > lag(temperature) over (order by year) then 'Yes' else 'No' end) HigherThanPreviousYear
from temp
```

You can select year from above query as below:

```
select distinct year
from (
    select *
        , (case when Temperature > lag(temperature) over (order by year) then 'Yes' else 'No' end) HigherThanPreviousYear
    from temp
) t
where HigherThanPreviousYear = 'yes'
```

You can also user self join a below (Though it looks simple it will be slightly slower than the above query):

```
select y.year
from temp y
inner join temp py on y.year = py.year + 1
    and y.Temperature > py.Temperature
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but How do I display just years having temperature more than previous year? I dont want it in YES and NO format